# React native android app closing on auto redirect from app browser to app

Tags: android, react-native, inappbrowser

I am doing Login with facebook in react native using the Authorization code grant type. Using the module React Native App Auth. When I click on Login with facebook it is opening a browser in my app and showing me the facebook login module after I logged in successfully I have placed code to redirect to app. But my app is closing on auto-redirection and if I try in normal chrome browser the app is opening fin with the same link. Will there be any difference for normal browser and browser opening in the app?

Android Logcat :

```
4-10 16:10:12.758 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@96cdd71[AuthorizationManagementActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
04-10 16:10:12.942 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=73
04-10 16:10:12.952 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@3b953f4[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
04-10 16:10:12.964 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@3b953f4[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
04-10 16:10:12.980 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@96cdd71[AuthorizationManagementActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
04-10 16:10:12.989 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@96cdd71[AuthorizationManagementActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
04-10 16:10:14.765 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@96cdd71[AuthorizationManagementActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
    dispatchDetachedFromWindow
04-10 16:10:14.767 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=56
04-10 16:10:14.778 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()
04-10 16:10:14.785 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/ViewRootImpl@3b953f4[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
    dispatchDetachedFromWindow
04-10 16:10:14.790 11363-11363/com.<app-name> D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=52
```

Android Manifest:

```
 <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
          <data android:scheme="app"
                android:host="<app-name>"
                android:pathPrefix="/oauth"
          />
        </intent-filter>
```

Am i missing any setting in manifest file?

Comment: You need to share your code to be able to help you

Comment: @m9m9m, were you able to solve this at the end?